# How do i get dropdown meny by clicking on MenuItem?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar

I have problems with implementing a dropdown (like a spinner) list in my customized ActionBar. I've tried several solutions, including getActionView() but it doesn't work :/

```
 Here is my code; @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.planner_menu, menu);
MenuItem category_item = menu.findItem(R.id.CategoryAppointment);
    Spinner spinner =(Spinner) category_item.getActionView();

    String[] categories = new String[]{"meeting","training","puls","medicin","bloodsample"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,categories);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          parent.setSelection(position);

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        String category = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                                "OnItemSelectedListener : " + category, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // Take string and compare it in database.
                        DB.getAllAppointmentsByCategory(category);
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        // Take string and compare it in database.
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        // Take string and compare it in database.
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        // Take string and compare it in database.
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        // Take string and compare it in database.
                        break;
                }
            }

@Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

for (int j = 0; j < menu.size(); j++) {
    MenuItem item = menu.getItem(j);
    Log.d("TAG", "set flag for " + item.getTitle());
    item.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

}
return true;}
```

And here is the the options from the meny.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.AllAppointments:

            //DB.getUsersAppointment();
            return true;
        case R.id.WeekAppointment:
            //DB.getUsersAppointmentByWeek(date);
            return true;

        case R.id.CategoryAppointment:
//            setupSpinner();
            //DB.getUsersAppointmentByCategory(category);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

The code from the XML file.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".Planning">

<item android:id="@+id/AllAppointments" android:title="All"
    android:orderInCategory="10"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText">
</item>
<item android:id="@+id/WeekAppointment"
    android:title="Week"
    android:orderInCategory="10"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText"
    >
</item>
<item android:id="@+id/CategoryAppointment"
    android:title="Cathegories"
    android:orderInCategory="10"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText"
    >
</item>
```

`
In item id -> CategoryAppointment I want to show a dropdown meny where the user can choose between diffent categories and then list out the data from the database. 
I've been working with this for the past hours but I can't seem to fix it. Can someone please explain to me what I have to do and what it is that i'm doing wrong here.

Thank you.